# Exception is not getting catch in rescue block (retry)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, exception

The exception `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError.new` is not being caught in my rescue block (retry). Why I am not able to catch Exception?

```
  attr_accessible :original_updated_at

  def original_updated_at
    @original_updated_at || updated_at.to_f
  end

  def set_total_and_buckets_used
    tries = 0
    begin
      if total_approved - attributes["total_amount_used"] < 0
          raise Exception.new("Total amount used is greater than approved")
      elsif self.updated_at.to_f == original_updated_at
        @original_updated_at = nil
        raise ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError.new("Car is changed while you were editing")
      else
        self.with_lock do
          attributes["updated_at"] = Time.now.utc
          Product.where(:id => self.id).update_all(attributes)
          self.attributes = attributes
        end
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError => e
      if tries < 3
        tries += 1
        retry
      else
        raise Exception.new(timeout.inspect)
      end
    end
    self.reload
    attributes
  end
```

Comment: Never raise or catch `Exception`. Either do `raise "Total amount used is greater than approved"` or a more specific error class.

Comment: Looks like you're not building that exception correctly. Here's the constructor signature: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/StaleObjectError.html#method-c-new

Comment: How do you know it's not being caught?